# Returning to Chess Tournaments: Does My Old FIDE Rating Still Apply?

Tags: fide, rating, tournament

Years ago, I was an active chess player with a rating of 1450. I plan to return to the scene by participating in an official tournament.

My question is, will my previous rating be retained or reset due to my prolonged absence?

Comment: Your rating still applies, though in 1st of march there will be rating reform - rating floor will be raised to 1400 and all U2000 players will get a one-time rating boost of 0,4 * (2000 - rating).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is, will my previous rating be retained or reset due to my prolonged absence?

6 years is not that long for FIDE. They still have [their rating records for you](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/42582245/chart) and when you resume it will be with a standard rating of 1450 and rapid rating of 1442 unless they apply the anti-deflation adjustments they were talking about a few months ago. In that case just over 200 rating points would be added to your ratings.

Answer (score 2):

I took a break for 24 years, with a 1390 score. They actually increased my score, to make up for the non official training time I took when I was away in Japan with one of the more unknown Grandmasters.

Comment: 24 years ago the FIDE floor was 1800 so either you are talking about some other rating system or your memory is faulty, to put it politely.